# How to prevent button function defined by useLayoutEffect from being executed automatically after rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-navigation

In the `React Native 0.61.5/React 16.9.0` app with `React-Navigation 5.x`, a button in header is defined with `navigation.setOptions` in `useLayoutEffect`. Here is the portion of code in the function component Chat:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <Button onPress={handleAddPicture()} title="Image Picker" />  //handleAddPicture is defined in the same component
      ),
    });
  }, []);

useEffect(() => {
  //retrieve data from backend server
}, [])
```

The `useLayoutEffect` is used to add a button in the header for user to pickup image on local file system. The issue is that as soon as the component is rendered, the image picker button is automatically clicked somehow and `handleAddPicture` function is called. How to prevent the execution of `handleAddPicture` from happening automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is a pretty simple one, you just need to not call `handleAddPicture` yourself. When the Button is pressed, the code bound to onPress will be called, so you just need to remove the parentheses from it and it'll work.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <Button onPress={handleAddPicture} title="Image Picker" />  //handleAddPicture is defined in the same component
      ),
    });
  }, []);

useEffect(() => {
  //retrieve data from backend server
}, [])|
```

Note that you can also use it like this if you want to call the function yourself or do other actions than that one function call.

```
        <Button onPress={()=>handleAddPicture()} title="Image Picker" />  //handleAddPicture is defined in the same component
```

Answer (score 1):

As @ZacharyHaber above had said you need to just change your `Button` component `onPress` handler.  When you pass a function into an `onPress` in the following form `onPress={handlePress()}` you are telling React to call the function.

Whenever you want to make a component clickable with some function but not call it on mount you need to just pass a reference to the function by excluding the () i.e. `onPress={handlePress}`.  This same concept also applies to passing functions through props to child components etc.